# Identify a file or directory on a SSH machine using net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient api.

Tags: ssh

I want to identify whether a the given path is a valid path for file or directory using net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient api and based on i need to take decision that if it is a valid file path then i need to access its parent directory. my code looks like below>
        SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
        String rsaKey = "e3:27:12:a9:62:9a:46:cc:98:ee:0d:b7:38:72:a0:63";
        String host = "10.235.1.154";
        String uName = "root";
        String pwd = "pspl@123"; 
        String url = "/root/ram2.log/";
        String testUrl = host + url;
        ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(rsaKey);
        List fileItems = new ArrayList();

```
    1.try {
    2.  ssh.connect(host);
    3.  ssh.authPassword(uName,pwd);
    4.  SFTPClient sftp = ssh.newSFTPClient();
    5.  
    6.  if(testUrl.startsWith(host)){
    7.      String[] splitedStrings = testUrl.split(host);
    8.      String str = splitedStrings[1];
    9.      url = str;
    10. }else{
    11.     url = url;
    12. }
    13. 
    14.
    15. List<RemoteResourceInfo> fileInfoList = sftp.ls(url, new RemoteResourceFilter() {
    16.     public boolean accept(RemoteResourceInfo rrInfo) {
    17.         return rrInfo.getName().charAt(0) != '.';
    18.     }
    19. });
    20. 
    21. 
    22. for (RemoteResourceInfo fileInfo : fileInfoList) {
    23.     //files.add(str + "/" + fileInfo.getName());
    24.     String fileName = fileInfo.getName();
    25.     if (fileInfo.isDirectory()) {
                FileItem childFileItem = new FileItem();
                childFileItem.setPath(host + url + fileName);
                fileItems.add(childFileItem);
            } else {
                int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                String ext = dotIndex > 0 ? fileName
                        .substring(dotIndex + 1) : "";
                FileItem childFileItem = new FileItem();
                childFileItem.setPath(host + url + fileName);
                childFileItem.setDirectory(false);
                fileItems.add(childFileItem);
            }
        }




    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't resolve host : {} "+ host);
    }
    return fileItems;
```

Problem: Line no. 15 is throwing error saying no such file if I m giving the path as "/root/ram2.log/" even though the file ram2.log does exis on server.

Any help on this wud be graet helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lstat` to get information about file system objects.

```
FileAttributes attributes = sftp.lstat(url);
if (attributes.getType() == FileMode.Type.DIRECTORY) {
    ...
}
```

But i think your actual problem is that something is odd with the directory "/root/ram2.log/". Maybe no permission, maybe it's not visible to you, maybe it contains a file with a name that isn't encoded properly.